# Google map with css "transform:scale"

Tags: css, google-maps, google-maps-markers, transform, scale

Good afternoon,

I have an issue with a google map and css "transform:scale".
My aim is to scale the map to 1.1 if the map is hovered. But if i do this i cant click the markern anymore. I have tried to solve it with jquery but i got no success. 
Anybody here who has a solution?

Here is a fiddle: [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2r72x1x6/)

I tought that first switch the scaled size, then load the map, and then switch to old size will get it to work, but no success.

Here is my abortive try..

```
$("#map").hover(function(){
$("#map").width(880).height(617.1).load('/index.html', function () {
initialize();
}).width(800).height(561);  
});
```

Thanks for helping

Manuel Strohmaier

Answer (score 1):

The problem is quite easy to explain, but unfortunately I haven't good solution now.

Take a look: http://take.ms/2E3fV

[image: Google Map click element for marker after css transform]

On image I mark rectangle which shows where exactly is now an element wchich responds for a click action on google map marker. So simply, when You scale map with CSS, each image scales too but position coordinates (`left, right, top, bottom`) don't change.

Theoreticaly You can inspect Google Map's code and fix this position in any way, but:

- it's not universal solution (not for dynamic pin for example)
- it can be changed in future (class name, or even whole solution)
- it's rather hack than solution

Answer (score 1):

what's your intens using transform:scale ? 
why don't you use zoom for that ?

check my code snippet i edited from yours, may be this help you...

```js
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922);
    var myLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(-22.363882, 125.044922);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatlng
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
    var contentString = "Pls help me to get the right position :)"
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });

    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'First Marker'
    });

    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng2,
        map: map,
        title: 'Sec Marker'
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'mouseover', function () {
        map.setZoom(14);
        infowindow.open(map, marker1);
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
#map {
     height: 400px;
     width: 400px;
     margin: auto;
     padding: 0px;
     top:100px;
 }

.scale {
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
#map.scale:hover {
    transform: scale(1.9);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<body>
    <div id="map" class="map scale"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I use the transform:scale to enlarge not the content inside the map, but rather the whole content of a div with the map inkl. title, sidebar, north arrow, logo etc..

Comment: that's it bro, i only scale it max in 1.9. May be you can take it and improve it...

Comment: yes and thats exactly the problem we get with transform:scale. Now it isnt possible to zoom or click the markers in the right position.

Comment: yes, you're right about that. Because don't look google maps as a one image, but it contains more partial image. if you force using transform scale that's the problem you get..

Comment: okey thanks and you know no solution for this ? i thinks its hard to do !